# git merge added a ton of commit messages

Tags: git

I was doing work on a separate branch from master for some amount of time. At some point, I finished up the work I was doing on the branch and I wanted to merge it back into master. In order to bring myself up to date on the latest master and make sure everything worked before I merged my branch back, I did `git checkout master`, `git pull origin master`, `git checkout mybranch`, `git merge master`. Made a few tweaks and great, now I have the latest changes in the code and it's all good... but now I have a crapload of commit messages which come from others who have been working on the branch and have nothing to do with my changes, which obscure the changes I made in my code.

I'd really like to get rid of those external commit messages (and perhaps many of the more mundane commit messages I had made myself while working). But I'd settle for simply collapsing all of the work I had done on my branch into a single "implemented X feature" commit message, so that all of the changes between my work and the master branch are clear, and there isn't a huge amount of clutter in the commit history.

Possibly complicating things is that I had already pushed to origin before I realized the state of my commit history, so the fix for this would need to be able to be applied to the remote repository.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: so your concern is just about the commit msgs in the `git log`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix it, but to avoid the problem next time, you can use `git rebase remote/branch`. Rebase doesn't add commit message.

Answer (score 0):

After pushing to origin its a real mess here, but next time best thing is:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~N (where N is the number of commits backwards)
```

Then you `squash` the commits in the opened editor to make them into a single commit, you can read more [here](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

Answer (score 0):

> but now I have a crapload of commit messages

If you're not interested in commits incorporated by merge, just add `--first-parent`, e.g.

```
git log --oneline --first-parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerend about other commit msgs in the log you can do somehting ike this:

`git log --author=<name or email>`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all of the changes on your branch into a single commit with the `--squash` option for merge, like this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash your-branch
```

With the squash option the changes will not be committed, so you could remove some of the changes if you don't want them and then commit. The commit message is pre-populated with all of the commit messages from the branch, which is pretty handy.

Just keep in mind that this will be recorded like a single commit on your main branch, there won't be merged branch in the commit graph.